# How about forcing answers when there is rapid down-voting without any answers?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243404/pay-real-money-to-set-bounties-another-method-not-replacing-rep-method) was rapidly down-voted without any response of material to help the user understand why the question was so poorly asked that it justified such rapid and massive down-voting. I have seen this happen before, but didn't bother tracking those questions, so for now I have only the one example to provide. My opinion is that down-voting in most of such cases is more for -1 disagree than for any genuine issues with the question.

I just want to suggest that if a question has no answers and some agreed upon negative score (-5? -10?), then no further down-votes should be allowed until an answer is provided. I cannot see any useful purpose to massively down-voting a question without providing a single answer.

Please understand this is not intended to be a discussion on the topic of that question.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Generally a lot of downvotes would indicate there is a problem with the question that makes it unanswerable.

Comment: So I shouldn't be able to downvote an abusive, offensive or spam post without answering it if it's at -5 already? Why not?

Comment: @animuson Then leave a comment or make an edit. Drive-by down-voting does not help improve the question and likely sends the asker away. What is the point of going lower than -5 without any feedback?

Comment: @JonK There is already a flagging feature to take care spam, abusive, offensive, and other posts that violate SE policies.

Comment: @Paul But there *are* comments on that question, which indicate problems with the question's quality and/or the idea presented in general.

Comment: You appear to think downvotes are there just to tell the OP that the question is somehow lacking. Downvoting is there to tell *everyone else* that a question is lacking, and not worth their time. There are too many bad questions to go and tell each and every new poster what might be wrong. We expect users to *read the help provided up front* instead.

Comment: As such, it makes **no sense** to require answers (or did you mean *comments* instead, perhaps?) before more down-votes are allowed. All you'll get then is comments along the lines of *Unicorns are cool, I want a Unicorn!*, e.g. nonsense just to fill the comment requirement. You won't necessarily get any constructive feedback.

Comment: A score of -5 *is* feedback. It means "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Why should we reward bad questions with answers? Why should we take the time to provide an answer when the asker didn't take the time to ask a good, on-topic question?

Comment: @animuson The comments on that question can easily be fixed by editing _or_ by providing an ANSWER.

Comment: In this case, I downvoted your post for your lack of research. We have discussed this topic **to death**. There will never be a requirement to comment when down-voting posts, because that leads to revenge voting, whining, name calling, etc.

Comment: @Paul Are you aware that voting is different on meta sites? Downvotes on a feature request mean people disagree with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

Comment: @Paul It's not possible for us to modify a question when we can't tell exactly what they're asking about in the first place. We're not telepathic here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters There is nothing wrong with the linked question that would be revealed by RTFM. Yes, I mean answers, not just comments.

Comment: @Paul: that makes **no sense** whatsoever. Most questions I down-vote are unanswerable. Forcing answers just to downvote is going to get you the same behaviour: nonsense answers that are not helpful to anyone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I read that question and this is not a duplicate. I am not encouraging explanation of a down-vote, rather discouraging drive-by -1 disagree votes.

Comment: @Paul Let me ask you this: If it had 25 upvotes rather than 25 downvotes, would you still be complaining that no one has provided any reasoning why it would be a *good* idea rather than a *bad* idea?

Comment: @Paul: 1) such down votes do not require discouraging. 2) requiring that answers be posted goes against everything Stack Exchange sites stand for, which is to curate quality questions with quality answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did a bit of searching and did not find this suggestion made previously.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What is lacking about the quality of the suggestion made in the question I linked that was not repaired by a good Samaritan community member? How is the community helped by discouraging people from ever taking part? Why is it acceptable to take a question that is perfectly valid and down-voting it to -20 in less than an hour?

Comment: @Paul: That is a **feauture request**, and a ridiculous one at that. That post is being downvoted because no-one here wants to see that implemented.

Comment: @Paul: in that case I'll link you to the Meta FAQ: [How does Meta Stack Exchange work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is it SE policy that if something has been discussed, it shall never be discussed again? Even if the discussion is providing a different proposal than has been proposed before?

Comment: @Paul: note that I left a comment on that suggestion explaining my reasoning. Why would others have to repeat that reasoning if they agree with that? I don't think that that post warrants an answer, especially not in the state that it is in.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, thanks for that. If only THAT would come up in the suggested links when posting. However, there are other instances when I see abuse of down-voting, and you can bank on my coming back here the next time I see them.

Comment: @Paul: Please do take some time to learn about the community here first. Lurk. Read posts. Read the FAQ.

Comment: @Paul: also see [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44188)

Comment: @MartijnPieters As I stated in my question, this is NOT to be a discussion on the topic of the linked question. Did you read that part? Also, if you comment is so 'great', why not make it an answer instead? Wouldn't my feature-request have encouraged you to leave an answer, which is what the user is looking for?

Comment: @Paul: I did not make it an answer because the question is **unclear**. I don't think it is answerable in its current state. I **suspect** the question is a duplicate, or at least can be answered in the same vein as other 'real money' questions here on Meta, giving it another reason not to answer the type of question *again*.

Comment: @JonK Well, that would be a bummer, because I was going to award a bounty to Frank for being the only one courageous enough to leave a real answer, plus this is likely the last time I take part in Meta SE.

Comment: @Paul I would also like to add that your proposal and comments seem to ignore one key concept: some questions are just irredeemably bad. These questions do not deserve an answer and will not be improved by an answer. In those cases, a downvote is a signal to others to not waste time reading or interacting with that question. Downvoting those questions is a service to the community, and forcing people to post useless, undeserved answers to provide that service is counterproductive.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Then I would suggest that my proposal would further relieve time wasted, because if a question has reached the maximum possible and still has no answer, then it must be pretty bad. However, I would bet that no matter what the number of down-votes a question has, many members will read the question anyway, so really nothing will save time in either case. However, my proposal would encourage _answers_ to be provided in places they currently are not.

Comment: I don't really understand how your proposal would "relieve time wasted" by forcing people to do extra work. And the point I'm trying to make is that a downvote often implies that a question either cannot be answered or is not worth answering. Forcing people who are communicating that to also answer a question is nonsensical. Not all questions deserve answers, and those that are downvoted are probably the least deserving. It's also worth noting that when a question (on any non-meta site) with enough downvotes will be removed from the active questions page, ensuring that most do not see it.

Comment: One important thing that you're perhaps not aware of is the "roomba" job that runs once a day. It looks through the list of downvoted, unanswered questions and deletes any that meet its criteria (one of which is that it's been around for a certain length of time, I believe it's 30 days). This automatic weeding of low quality posts would stop working if you force people to answer downvoted questions.

Comment: @JonK If the point of SE is to answer questions, why seek justifications to delete them? Shouldn't we be looking for ways to increase the number of questions answered? And besides, when questions are at the bottom and have no answers, then they can still be zipped away.

Comment: Quality of questions always trump quantity of questions

Comment: "Shouldn't we be looking for ways to increase the number of questions answered?" - Yes and no. The aim of the Stack Exchange network is to be a bank of knowledge in the form of *high quality* questions *and* answers. This proposal would artificially inflate the answer rate for questions across the network, but would do very little or be actively detrimental to the objective of being a bank of high quality questions and answers.

Comment: @JonK Doesn't the voting system determine the quality of the question? And is there no interest in keeping new members around? How would you feel if you found this really cool looking site that encourages people to ask questions (even without creating an account!), asked a question, and then was basically told to go screw yourself? I don't think you would come back.

Comment: Yes it does - and the important point here is that your proposal would reduce the effectiveness of SE's *most important metric for indicating quality*. Stack Exchange *is* elitist to an extent (how much varies from site-to-site), and as a result isn't always the nicest place for newcomers. However, it's a necessary evil unless we want to degrade into something like Yahoo Answers. We do also have some excellent guidelines to teach new users how to interact with the SE sites in a positive way from the start - but most of them completely ignore them!

Comment: @JonK We have a phrase in marketing, "the market doesn't lie." If the newcomers are consistently having trouble, the problem is not with the newcomers. I still don't see why there is greater value in having a question garner -20 votes and then sending the user packing vs. limiting to say 5 or 10 and requiring an answer to encourage the user to stay.

Comment: Stack Exchange has no shortage of new users, although there is some truth to what you say. *However*, **forcing** an answer on a terrible question *is not the way to encourage them to stay*. It also doesn't do much to encourage them to improve any future questions, which could very well result in a net decrease in overall site quality, which in turn drives away the domain experts that helped to make places like Stack Overflow the de facto place to go if you have certain types of question. Fewer experts means fewer quality answers, means people go elsewhere to get them, etc...

Comment: @JonK It is not forcing an answer unless someone wants to further down-vote the question. I think it encourages useful labor to be put to better tasks. On Slashdot, the only comments I pretty much never read are the ones modded to -1, and I do this because I know that nearly all comments of -1 are not even worth expanding. The same would be done by the members of SE.

Comment: @JonK Remember that all boats rise with a rising tide.

Comment: Unless you drill a whacking great big hole in the bottom of the boat. Which is what people feel that this feature request amounts to.

Comment: The quality of questions is far more important than the quantity (though the latter is not unimportant at all) - the same goes for answers.  No one can force users to write a constructive post on the 6th (or whichever) downvote - so a series of nonsense answers to questions that for whatever reason do not match what SE is striving to achieve (quality questions and answers).  Here in meta, all the community have the **right** to epress their opinion anonymously and the community does not, in any way, have to answer to you, me or anyone else.

Comment: @Gone Yes, SE is striving to achieve an elitist online community of technophiles. No wonder all the non-tech sites are wastelands. Ever notice how many goose-eggs there are in the Android Enthusiast site? Perhaps if SE did a better job at retaining the lower- and novice-knowledge types, instead of skirting them away like so much trash, maybe there would be people around to answer some of those questions?

Comment: @Paul "elitist' is not constructive... and for the record, I am mainly a member on the science sites here.  I do have questions about programming, and I have found that with a simple search - all the answers I need are posted (even finished my PhD with some great questions and answers I found).  Lower and novice level (of which I am in regards to technology) are welcome to post, they just have to make sure their questions follow the guidelines, just everyone else has to follow them.

Comment: @Gone Just as I asked you before, and you failed to acknowledge my question (originally against your accusation) I have never stated that new users should not be required to follow the rules.

Comment: @Paul Can you edit your question to elaborate on how you believe requiring the sixth down-voter to answer (as well as requiring an answer from all those attempting to down-vote while that person was constructing *their* answer - recall this is a "rapid down-vote" scenario) if the five down-voters before him did not would provide a solution to the problem that you see? I am unclear on that, and I think it would help to clarify in general.

Comment: @JasonC The point is not the specific number.

Comment: @Paul Your proposal has to be able to be realistically implemented to be considered, though. So in that case: Can you edit your question to elaborate on how you believe requiring the `Nth` down-voter to answer (as well as requiring an answer from all those attempting to down-vote while that person was constructing *their* answer - recall this is a "rapid down-vote" scenario) if the `N-1` down-voters before him did not would provide a solution to the problem that you see? Also how should `N` be chosen? I am unclear on that, and I think it would help to clarify in general.

Comment: @JasonC Okay, marketers involved in pricing understand the psychology of additional digits. Why does something priced at $99.99 sell so much better than an otherwise identical product at $10.00? So on that, I recommend the the number of votes at 9, as this is still a single digit. However, since I'm not aware of where features are beta tested, I would recommend watching the behavior of new users who bump up against the limit.

Comment: @Gone You stated "Newcomers have to follow the rules as much as you and I do, no special provisions are given and nor should they be."

Comment: @Paul That seems like a reasonable rationale for `N`. Can you edit your question to elaborate on how you believe requiring the 10th down-voter to answer (as well as requiring an answer from all those attempting to down-vote while that person was constructing *their* answer - recall this is a "rapid down-vote" scenario) if the 9 down-voters before him did not would provide a solution to the problem that you see? I am unclear on that, and I think it would help clarify in general.

Comment: @Paul that is because you keep referring to new users and how the current process is 'scaring them off' - there would be no problem if they just read documentation and searched to see if their question had been asked before.

Comment: @Paul as an aside and response to your name-calling remarks - the fact people are answering in comments and as answers shows that we care enough to interact and particularly in Jason C's case try and help you clarify your proposal.  We don't have to, as like everyone else, we have lives to live and other things to do.  But we are here, trying to get you to clarify what you are asking and explaining why the proposal is being downvoted.

Comment: @Paul Earlier you wrote, *"Nobody here has had any interest in address any of the questions. I ask them, then they ignore them and move on to ask more questions."* -- I believe that applies on both sides. See my previous comment - unless you can clarify and elaborate on how you believe this proposal will solve the problem you describe, you will have to accept that it will not be well-received.

Comment: I read the question, understood it, disagreed, downvoted, and left.  Not sure why there's an issue with that.  You suggest a FR on meta, people vote on it.  If it's good, it gets upvoted and attention.  If it's bad, it gets downvoted and ignored.  There is no problem here.

Comment: I am strongly against *any* feature request that artificially limits downvotes, but doesn't apply the same to upvotes.  That skews the quality metric, which is absolutely *critical*.  Apply this to upvotes as well, and I'll re-read your proposal.  Until then, -1.

Answer (score 25):

I disagree with this proposal. I have nothing constructive to add, but I am just posting an answer because I am required to in order to down-vote, since there are already too many down-votes on the proposal.

---

The above is essentially the type of answer that this proposal would attract to questions. Not to mention all the extra NAA flags that would go along with it. This is not particularly useful, I believe.

Comment: +1 great and pertinent answer

Comment: I have added a bit of explanation underneath, in case it was *too* meta.

Comment: And I flagged it as useless, which is what the flag system is for.

Comment: @Paul Was it useless, or are you irritated that it was spot on to the type of answers your proposal would attract (not just attract, but *require*)?

Comment: It is a very good answer with a good edit explaining the reality of the situations should such a system be implemented.  Disagreeing =/= useless.

Comment: @Paul Hey, I thought it was clever. I could have just typed the *other* style of answer this requirement would attract, such as: "asdfasdf required to downvote". Also don't forget the slew of inevitable feature-requests to remove the requirement because folks are sick of having to post arbitrary answers to down-vote on meta, and sick of reading them.

Comment: @JasonC Also, you can have fewer people taking part in the community overall, because way too often SE is a Question and Comment site, most especially when new users arrive.

Comment: @Paul Well: 1. Comments are participation. 2. I speak only for myself, but I know that if I had to post an answer to every unanswered meta question I down-voted, I would probably just stop checking meta completely.

Comment: @JasonC The proposal covers having zero answers. If there is one answer, down-vote all you like, and nowhere did I state there has to be any explanation of a down-vote.

Comment: @JasonC Are comments what drive people to SE? I think people come here for answers.

Comment: @Paul I did say "unanswered". Your proposal requires the sixth down-voter to explain themselves in an answer if the five before him did not. This does not seem to be helpful. Also your example question was a meta question. People come to meta for discussion. Comments are a valid way to participate in those discussions.

Comment: @Paul When I was new to SE, I didn't get many downvotes, because I read the help center of the site I was interested in, and watched for a while to see how it worked.

Comment: @Paul This proposal is a bad idea. It's OK to have bad ideas. I have terrible ideas pretty regularly, if it makes you feel better. Accept it gracefully. Your next idea might be a great one. This won't diminish that. Try not to tie your self-image too closely to how your SE questions are received, it is not healthy.

Comment: @Paul [This community welcomes plenty of new feature requests](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request?sort=votes&pageSize=15). For your first comment question, if you are referring to *"What is the point of going lower than -5 without any feedback?"*, it was answered [quite clearly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243425/how-about-forcing-answers-when-there-is-rapid-down-voting-without-any-answers/243429?noredirect=1#comment795550_243425), and quickly afterwards; you ignored it presumably because you did not agree, but unsatisfactory answer != no answer.

Comment: @JasonC No, it does not answer my question of What is the point of going lower than -5 without any feedback? The response was, "A score of -5 is feedback" is not an answer to my question of why is going lower without feedback useful? Do you get it?

Comment: @Paul The score *is* feedback, and the point of that answer is that the premise of the question is incorrect. It is a valid answer. *There is no such thing as a question with a score of -5 that does not have feedback*, so it does not make sense to ask about a question with "a score of -5 without feedback". This does not exist. Your assumption that the post score is not feedback is incorrect, and *that is your answer*.

Comment: @Paul By the way, [check out this SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/245619). The "Positive" / "Neutral" / "Negative" columns show the count of questions with positive, 0, or negative score, for each tag, also counts closed questions. As you can see, the ratio of positive is quite high for every tag. Do you still believe this is not a generally accepting community? Do not confuse reaction to your individual ideas with general behavior. A welcoming community is still not obligated to accept ideas without criticism. Now, please learn to take criticism gracefully.

Comment: @JasonC Yes, the syntax was not correct, but I think to most people with at least an 8th grade reading ability I am meaning feedback _beyond_ the down-voting.

Comment: @JasonC Does that query include deleted posts?

Comment: @JasonC To be honest, I have no idea what the data in that report means.

Comment: @Paul It includes closed posts but not deleted, as that info is unfortunately not available to us general public civilians. So of course there is some bias towards positive. [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/245621/positive-0-negative-scored-questions-by-tag) is the query with a proper description. It includes counts of positive, 0, and negative scoring questions by tag on meta.

Comment: @Paul Re: The "feedback" comment; others cannot guess what you mean and a good communication strategy (and good way to improve reception of ideas) is to always be clear, recognize that sometimes you may not be as clear as you think, and try to stay as open-minded (difficult sometimes) as possible.

Comment: @JasonC If it does not include deleted posts, then it is particularly biased against my claims.

Comment: @JasonC Guess what? I address his question in my original question when I stated "if a question has no answers and a score of -5, then no further down-votes should be allowed until an answer is provided. I cannot see any useful purpose to massively down-voting a question without providing a single answer." I _already_ responded to his question in my question, which, naturally, according to SE Meta, makes me the bad guy.

Comment: @Paul You are resistant to the idea that this is a welcoming community because if you accepted that it was, then that would validate the critics of your proposal here, which would force you to accept that this is a genuinely bad idea. So you are welcome to pretend we are evil if that's what it takes to discount what we say. Blame us, not your idea. That's fine, but then this may not be the community you seek. Unfortunately, I think it's counter-productive for me to try and argue with your subconscious rationalizations, and I will not continue. I have nothing new to add.

Comment: Another to consider, the downvotes could be taken as the community reading, considering and saying 'no, thanks' to this proposal, it does not mean that they are being mean (disagree =/=rude or mean), it just means that many are considering what is best for the site, which is more important than what is better for a few individuals in this case.

Comment: @Paul "I see, as usual, you guys cower away." - They aren't cowering away. They're providing you with reasoned arguments with data to back it up, which you appear to be simply dismissing because it doesn't back up the point you're trying to make. You're *not listening* to the huge amount of feedback that you're being provided, and people are just getting tired of banging their heads against the proverbial wall. They're not the ones who seem to have an axe to grind, and they're understandably just washing their hands of this and walking away. As I am about to do. Because it's 2 in the morning.

Comment: @JonK But that is what happens every time.

Comment: @Paul If you find you have a way of getting people to bang their heads against walls every time, you might benefit from some reflection! Realistically, it is more likely that the issue is on your end rather than with everybody who is not you (although we do have skeptics.se if you have a conspiracy theory; but be warned, *they might be in on it, too*).

Answer (score 13):

I think forcing answers is a bad idea. Anyone can vote how they want, pretty much. If they choose to downvote, it's not abuse. They are [encouraged to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes), but not required to do so, because you can't force them to post a constructive comment, and these discussions often lead to heated arguments, which are not constructive either.

Here on Meta Stack Exchange, [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions are voted up if people like them, and down if they don't. Leaving a comment is nice, but not absolutely necessary to send the message. The question you used as an example was obviously (to me) a bad idea, so I downvoted. I might have commented, but a comment I agreed with had already been posted, so I upvoted that instead. Same with this post.

It wasn't the post quality so much (although it helped) that caused the downvoting, so much as the content of the feature-request, which wasn't a good idea.

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted the answer just because you have the decency to make one.

Comment: Spot on, for the record, I downvoted the question cited and also agreed with the comment made. I upvoted this answer because it I agree wholeheartedly with it.  But the fact is, I do not have to and the namecalling above really convinces me to continue to not to.

Answer (score 5):

Votes (up or down) need to be anonymous and without cap or any action required other than the vote itself.

This is because we want, "need", people to vote, and cannot risk losing votes from users who wont be *forced* to make answer (or comment). Stopping people voting means you risk getting a less accurate representation of the general user opinion.

You also then only receive votes from user willing to answer (or comment), and by tunnelling votes to a certain "type" of person there is a danger of only getting a "certain type" of mindset/opinion each time.

Open community works as you get opinions from all kinds of people/thoughts/ideas, and while comments and answers are more useful in terms of raw opinion, simply having *votes* from different users is paramount to ensuring a varied mindset and opinion.
Even if they all agree, and even if it's 30 downvotes. the "varied" user mindset agrees this question (or answer) is terrible, poor, not a good suggestion, etc.

If nothing else, they are just as *entitled* to vote as anyone who is happy to or wants to comment/answer, forced or not.

> How about forcing answers when there is rapid down-voting without any answers?

Sincerely, I get your logic, I do, and it's admirable your intentions are to improve the site by trying to get some answers out of people rather than a mass downvote attack (etc).

However, *forcing answers* for a downvote once a certain downvote threshold is met is not really realistic or useful at all.

Sorry, it's simply a bonkers idea.
Mad as a bag of frogs!

- You'll just (mostly) get poor answers, so your intentions to bring
  about *improvement* is completely lost
- You will lose votes, not good as mentioned above
- Rapid downvoting is perfectly fine as it simply signifies a poor
  question, or poor proposal. This is a big part of the site, and why
  it works well within a huge community

You are also "essentially" suggesting a cap which potentially (and likely will) **limit**:

1. How *bad* a question can be (determined by X max downvotes)
2. How many users can disagree with the idea/opinion/feature request
3. Allowing the first X users to the question to be able to downvote
   freely, and forcing the remaining ones to answer (or comment) is not
   fair, at all

These would be severely detrimental to the main premise of Stack, that good content is voted up, and bad is voted down out of sight.

Comment: You are correct, this would be detrimental to the main premise of SE, which does not have much to do with getting users from a broad base of interests outside of what is essentially STEM. Even consumer-facing STEM tangents are terrible, especially Android Central. Seemed like a perfect fit for SE, but nobody is interested in answering questions over there. That's because SE is terrible at recruiting and keeping users who are not core to STEM (but might be able to answer Android questions). This is just one way to try and encourage them to stay by giving them what they came for: an answer.

Comment: They certainly will get an answer, if their question is clear and within the guidelines of the SE rules.

Comment: @Paul STEM? not really - consider [Cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/), [Photography.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/), [Home Improvement.SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com/), [Bicycles.SE](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) and a lot more on the [Site list](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: @Gone What are the answer rates like on those sites? Seeing quite a few goose eggs on Home Improvement.

Comment: @Gone Go look at Android Central and then come talk to me about answers.

Comment: Th point is, the examples I gave are **established** and **graduated** sites, also consider the site [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Paul no thanks, just answering to the incorrect statement you made your comment about STEM sites.

Comment: @Gone Doesn't matter if they are 'established' or 'graduated' when nobody uses them.

Comment: Of course people use them, what absolute nonsense.

Comment: Does not mean that `nobody uses them`, as you're exaggerating, no point in discussing this.

Comment: @Gone Then why are you trolling me? You clearly made no points, just threw stuff up until I made a syntax error and then walk away like you've accomplished something.

Comment: @Paul By "Android Central", did you mean [android.se]? I admit the low activity there, but since I just recently started being active on that site, I don't have any idea why (edit: okay, just a guess, it's because Android is "fragmented" and noone has all models with various Android version to answer). On the other hand, take a look on [these sites which are not really STEM, 100% answered and have active users](http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered).

Comment: Even if the Android site was completely dead, I don't quite see how that makes the proposal a good idea.

Comment: @JasonC Because SE has various policies that send away people, one of them being -20 votes in 20 minutes with no real explanation why. Those users never come back, so we don't get the benefits of all the knowledge they could have provided on topics they do know something about.

Comment: @Paul So if the Android site were dead, regardless of all other sites, then we could (somehow) conclude that the Android site became dead because of rapid down-voting on questions, and forcing the 10th down-voter to post an answer would have (somehow) stopped it / will revive it, and therefore this would be a good proposal? ... What?

Comment: @Paul don't assume, I am in hospital and treatments do not run by your timetable, not that I have to answer to you. (That ma come as a shock to you, but I do **not** answer to you).

Comment: @Paul "*Because SE has various policies that send away people*" SE has no such "policy"! Stack has a function (downvote) and it doesn't send people away - it's their decision to go away from their not liking people disagreeing. I've proposed a few things which were *quite unpopular*. I didn't run for the hills, I engaged in debate and learned about things I did not know, as well as others seeing a few points I had. It's not just up to those downvoting to debate this, and if the proposer runs away, what is the point of us answering/commenting anyway?

Comment: @Paul As per my answer, I see your logic and attempt to make an improvement. I don't disagree with the "*potential issue*" you have identified, I (as do most others) simply disagree with the "*proposed solution*". If you feel this issue is substantial enough to warrant a resolve, don't necessarily post a *feature request*, post a discussion, pointing out why you think it could be a big issue. *However* - make sure you have evidence, that is links to heavily downvoted questions with no comments or answers. I doubt you'll find more than a handful (Barring crap programming question of course).